# OutOfMemoryException thrown in C++/CLI code when accessing native C++ code

Tags: c++, .net, 64-bit, c++-cli, out-of-memory

I have a strange CLR **OutOfMemoryException** in a **64bit C++/CLI** process which has mixed native and managed C++ code inside. The process has the following structure:

1. Native C++ code (Main binary)
2. Managed C++/CLI code (Main binary)
3. C# code (External assembly)

Both main binary and external assembly are built for x64 platform. The managed C++/CLI layer (2) serves as an adapter between native C++ code (1) and C# code (3) which is actually a UI layer working with WPF. .NET Framework version is 4.0.

So I have the Main Binary (1 and 2) built with /MACHINE:X64 and /CLR which makes native C++ code (1) to work perfectly with >4Gb of memory consumed by the process, but C++/CLI layer code (2) throws an OutOfMemoryException once I step close to 4Gb. So far it happens in relatively random places but every time I saw it was in Managed-to-Native transitions when C++/CLI code tried to access a native method.

It seems like C++/CLI code inside Main binary doesn't feel itself as a x64-ready code, while the tools tell that the binary is in PE+ 64bit ready format and the native code works well with >4Gb. According to ANTS memory profiler and CLRProfiler the managed heaps are almost empty (several hundred of kb).

What could I miss? Doesn't it look like I'm linking to wrong .NET framework assemblies which are not x64-ready? Where should I look first?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just in case, make sure you unchecked the *Prefer 32-bit* checkbox in the C# project properties, although I don't think it's that, since it should choose 64 bit anyway because of the 64 bit dependency.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Lucas. No, this checkbox is unchecked. Also I never OOM'ed in the C# external assembly, I always have this issue in the C++/CLI code when I access the native code. Maybe C# project properties could make wrong (32bit) external assemblies to load instead of 64bit ones and they are used when I do managed-to-native c++ transition, but all these sound like a superstition. Don't really know where to look next..